# App can't be built on TestFlight but can be run and archive

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Here's the error code:

```
[15:54:25]: [31mAsset validation failed Invalid MinimumOSVersion. Apps that only support 64-bit devices must specify a deployment target of 8.0 or later. MinimumOSVersion in 'APP_UAT.app/Frameworks/appuatx.framework' is '1.0'. (ID: 6e9f36b1-20c4-41e9-871d-3375d534678b) (90530)
[0m
[15:54:25]: [31mAsset validation failed Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle APP_UAT.app/Frameworks/appuatx.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0 (ID: 96078d4c-1e2f-41a9-982d-9449aad05022) (90362)
[0m
[15:54:25]: [31mAsset validation failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle APP_UAT.app/Frameworks/appuatx.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. (ID: c9aa26ab-c818-4497-86cb-b88c845f2b9e) (90208)
```

The problem is: There's no appuatx.framework. I couldn't find it anywhere in the project nor in the package dependency. The issued appeared in ShieldSDK.framework as well at first. But ShieldSDK.framework does exist and its Info.plist can be edited. appuatx.framework doesn't. After solving ShieldSDK.framework problem, appuatx.framework appears instead. It didn't show up before that.

It can be run and archive. And can be built via Jenkins. The problem only appear in TestFlight. How can I solve this?

I've tried to remove and add ShieldSDK. It didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This error says, that some framework has invalid "minimal os version" data. Try to update minimal os version for libraries and set, for example, iOS 13.0
If you provide info what framework provider you use (cocoa pods, spm, etc.), it would be possible to give more details instruction how to update this field